# CS50 "expected expression" for else statement in C?

Tags: c, cs50

I can't seem to find the reason for my last remaining bug. Sadly I dont have any real life developer friends I can hast for quick help so making this post was my only option.

**error given is 
57:13: error: expected expression
            else
            ^**

could someone maybe check over my code and hint me towards the problem ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // make sure command line input correct.
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Command line arguments can't be greater or lower then 2\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // get a valid key = key
    string key = (argv[1]);
    int lengthK = strlen(key);
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthK; i++)
    {
        if (!isalpha(key))
            printf("Key must be alphabetical \n");
        return 1;
    }

    //get plaintext
    string(plaintext) = get_string("Plaintext : ");

    //convert plaintext and keeping upper/lowercase in mind
    int i;
    int lengthP;
    int index;

    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (i = 0, index = 0, lengthP = strlen(plaintext); i < lengthP; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(plaintext[i]))
        {
            //change uppercase letters
            if (isupper(plaintext[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", (((plaintext[i] - 'A') + toupper(key[index]) - 'A') % 26) + 'A');
            }

            //change lowercase letters
            if (islower(plaintext[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", (((plaintext[i] - 'a') + key[index] - 'A') % 26) + 'a');
            }
            index = (index + 1) % lengthK;
            //rest
            else
            {
                printf("%c", (plaintext[i]));
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: When posting to Stack Overflow please take the time to clear up your indentation and remove any repeated blank lines that make the code unnecessarily long. Indentation is important because it communicates structure and, more importantly, intent. The error you have here would be apparent visually if this was properly and consistently indented.

Comment: If you're new at C you should go out of your way to ensure that *every* `if` statement uses enclosing `{ }` braces. Your `if (!isalpha(key))` will only print but *always* return. If you want both of those to be part of the `if` condition they must be braced. Indentation alone is not sufficient.

Comment: `string`  type is not available in c

Comment: Whats that `index = (index + 1) % lengthK;` doing between an `if` block and the `else`?

Comment: Why do you have the structure `if (...) { ... } statement; else { ... }`?

Comment: @suvojit_007 Thats some `typedef` from the darny `cs50.h`.

Comment: @J.Doe `cs50.h` needs to be deleted permanently from the internet.

Comment: @tadman Full ACK!

Comment: With proper indention, looking at said else for a few seconds should reveal the problem.

Comment: you are writing `if (!isalpha(key))` without curly braces

Comment: `string(plaintext) = ` is unconventional style, it would be clearer to write `string plaintext =`

Answer (score 3):

This is because your syntax is invalid.

The way you wrote it is interpreted that way

```
if (someConditions)
{
    /* do something */
}
someInstructions(); /* the if is now over since the curly brackets are closed and there was no else */

/* here is an else without if, which is a non sense */
else
{
    /* do something else */
}
```

You either

- Misplaced that instruction `index = (index + 1) % lengthK;`
- Misplaced the closing curly bracket of `if (isalpha(plaintext[i]))`

Answer (score 0):

You have a closing brace in the wrong place:

```
        if (isalpha(plaintext[i]))
        {
            ...
        index = (index + 1) % lengthK;

        //rest
        else
        {
            printf("%c", (plaintext[i]));
        }
        }    // <---- here
```

You need to move it above the `else`:

```
        if (isalpha(plaintext[i]))
        {
            ...
            index = (index + 1) % lengthK;
        }
        //rest
        else
        {
            printf("%c", (plaintext[i]));
        }
```

Comment: This may be `index = (index + 1) % lengthK;` which is misplaced and should be below the `else`

Comment: note: This would discard characters that are alpha but not upper or lower (locale-dependent what the size of that set is).